# Delete operation throws EmptyResultDataAccessException if there is nothing to delete, derived query doesn't

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a simple delete operation and using a derived query such as

```
deleteByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName)
```

doesn't throw an EmptyResultDataAccessException, comparing with

```
delete(String firstName)
```

which does if there is nothing to delete. How to deal with this situation?

Should I evaluate on the number of records returned by the operation and throw it by myself if it's 0?

Comment: Can you show the return types of the methods ?

Comment: the derived query has been tested with void and Integer. In integer case it returns the number of entities deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what delete method is that, but the `delete` I know receives an entity as parameter.

But to answer your question, you should first fetch the entity you want to delete, and if it's there (a.k.a Optional.isPresent) then `delete(said entity)`